# The expression is not valid after '>'

Tags: spotfire, tibco

In Spotfire, I created a Cross Table.  In the Cross table>Properties>Data>Limit data using expression:> I put the following:
Date([Discharge Date])=>'06-01-2019'
I get the error message "The expression is not valid after '>' on line 1 character 19"

I tried Date([Discharge Date])>'06-01-2019 but it still does not work

The code is Date([Discharge Date])=>'06-01-2019'

I hope to be able to use Date([Discharge Date])=>'06-01-2019' in the Cross table>Properties>Data>Limit data using expression:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAweY.png)

I tried the Date(2019,6,1) but still got the error message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX97F.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Spotfire Docs:

> Creates a Date from a column or values. If a single argument is given,
>   the input column can be of type String or DateTime. If a String is
>   specified, the date must be written on a form that Spotfire can
>   recognize and all parts of the date (year, month and day) must be
>   present.  If three integer arguments are given, then the first
>   argument is the year, the second is the month and the third is the
>   date in that month.
>
> Example: Date([Column]) Date(2007, 05, 17)

Change your date formatting to `[Discharge Date] >= Date(2019,06,01)` and try again.

Comment: I tried the Date(2019,6,1) but still got the error message.  Please see the image I uploaded in the original section.

Comment: Change `=>` to `>=`. If that works I will edit my answer